# How to ignore nested transactions using in-memory Sqlite on Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, aspnetboilerplate, abp, aspnetzero

I am using AspNetZero/ AspNetBoilerplate to do some automated tests and I configured my Module to not disable transactions

```
    Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsTransactional = false;
```

But it is not working and I am having the following message:

`Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsTransactional = false;`

My test is calling the following method:

```
   UnitOfWork(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)]
   public virtual async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(CreateEntryRequest input) 
   {
        // Some code here ...

       
   }
```

Did I miss any setting?

Answer (score 0):

```
[UnitOfWork(isTransactional: false)]
public GetTasksOutput GetTasks(GetTasksInput input)
{
    var tasks = _taskRepository.GetAllWithPeople(input.AssignedPersonId, input.State);
    return new GetTasksOutput
            {
                Tasks = Mapper.Map<List<TaskDto>>(tasks)
            };
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#non-transactional-unit-of-work

Comment: I tried to use it but doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
public virtual async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(CreateEntryRequest input)
{
  using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
  {
     // Some code here ...
  }
}
```